# getting string resource of android project from java file

Tags: java, android, android-context

I am defining a lot of my constant strings in the R.strings resource for my android project. However, i would like to use them in JUST a java file. Where the class is just a java class. Is there anyway to get that reference?

I am able to reference it, but i am unable to use the `Context.getString()` method, because it is only a java file.

What are my options here? Should i just define all my constant strings in this java file? Or can i still use the R.strings?

---

example

`getString(R.string.PLUS_SERVICE))`

This does not work, because i have no context.

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what these strings are. String constants are subtly different from string resources. Generally if these strings end up in user-facing text, you probably want to put them into string resources. This way they can be easily localized. If they are for exception messages, etc. then this is not really that important and they can go into constants.

If you need to use resources in a class without a `Context`, you need to give it access to one. You can either pass it into the method that uses it in an argument, or you can pass it to the constructor when creating the class and store it in a member.

Comment: Thank you, i like your explanation of when to use string constants and when to use resources.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
context.getString(R.string.PLUS_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Have you tried it,Cause I doubt because getApplicationContext() method is of Context class and in Java File context is not available so how can it' method be Accessible?

Comment: This will not work, because it is not available in JUST a java file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing,

Make `Constructor` in Java file to `accept Context as parameter` like,

```
public ClassName(Context c)
{
}
```

And pass context from activity when creating object,

```
new ClassName(ActivityName.this);
```

And now you can use that context variable in your Java File.

Comment: +1, thank you. This should work, i will try as soon as i get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said the resources are for UI.  If your class that needs these strings does not have access to the Context then they probably just need to be constants in that class.  If you need to force the Context to the class then you may need to re-evaluate your design because you are then making a functional library and not an OO design.  The access and use of the Resources should fall in naturally with a good OOD.

Answer (score 0):

try this
for example in fragment, use

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext().getString( R.string.resource )
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure:

```
Context context=this;
```

Is actually the Activity context, and then access to the string resource as:

```
String string = context.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.string_name)
```